# Java paint particular objects

Tags: java, swing, optimization, paint

I am writing a game in Java which is based on a grid top down view. I am not very familiar with the JPanel paintComponent() and repaint() methods and I am having trouble creating a fast screen painting function.
Each tile is an object with a Tile.paintTile(g,x,y) to paint the tile at (x,y) on g. I want to find a nice way to paint only specific tiles, however I cannot find out how to do this. 
I have a World class with a TileAt(x,y) to get the tile, but every attempt I have made has caused stuttering or thrown errors.
Any help is appreciated!
-Renmusxd

edit: what I tried:
I am not very used to Java graphics yet, I tried overwriting paintComponent and adding paintComponent(g,x,y) but it doesn't like my not calling repaint. I no longer have the code because I substituted it with a paintAll version. Sorry.

Comment: Are the Tile objects unique?  That is, is each Tile going to appear at exactly one spot?

Comment: *"but every attempt I have made"*  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  (And I mean 'in code' as opposed to 'in words').

Comment: You really ought to show what you've tried so far, BTW.

Comment: BTW - Swing or AWT?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your most successful attempt.

Comment: You could employee a double buffering technique where your render you updates to a off screen image and when required, paint the image via the components `paintComponent` method.  You probably need to look at the [`JComponent#repaint(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) method, which allows you to specify the area to repainted.  You might find it useful to have a read through [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it is easier to just repaint the entire screen every time - this should be fast enough using Swing on most modern machines.

If you really want to do partial updates, then the best approach is probably:

- Create an offscreen `BufferedImage`, which should be the same size as your game display area (or slightly larger if you want to allow for scrolling)
- Draw your tiles into this offscreen image.
- When you repaint your view (i.e. in the `paintComponent` method) then just draw the whole bufferedimage onto the screen in one go.